# Remove element with XSLT where CDATA value is empty

Tags: xml, xslt, element

I am quite new to XSLT and find it very hard to understand properly..

I want to achieve that every  element where my CDATA has no value should be removed from the XML.

My XML looks like this:

```
<description>
  <internet>
    <texts_short>
      <text locale="de"><![CDATA[]]></text>
      <text locale="en"><![CDATA[EXF/RETAIL]]></text>
    <texts_long>
      <text locale="de"><![CDATA[]]></text>
    </texts_long>
  </internet>
  <vehicle>
    <texts_short/>
    <texts_long>
      <text locale="en"><![CDATA[Backend Functions Bundle]]></text>
    </texts_long>
    <texts_text2speech>
      <text locale="de"><![CDATA[]]></text>
    </texts_text2speech>
  </vehicle>
</description>
```

I have already prepared the following XSLT which removes every text element with no condition:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I achieve that only the  elements with empty CDATA value will be removed - so that only the one with text "EXF/RETAIL" and "Backend Functions Bundle" will stay?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use `<xsl:template match="text[not(normalize-space())]"/>` but that will remove `text` elements having no content, an empty CDATA section, a CDATA section with only white space etc. There is no way in XSLT to know whether the element's content was provided in the lexical markup by a CDATA section or an ordinary text node.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like adding ***cdata-section-elements="text"*** to the output together with Martin Honnen's answer solved my problem:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text[not(normalize-space())]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```